# sql запрос, создание таблицы

Tags: sql, oracle

```
create table employess 
(
  num number(4,0) primary key, 
  fname varchar(100) not null, 
  bday date, 
  gender char(1,0) check(gender==f || gender == m) default m,
  jobb varchar(30) not null,
  wagerate number(2,1) check(wagerate>=0.1 && vagerate <=1.5) default 1, 
  sdate date not null, 
  address varchar(200) not null
);
```

Выдает ошибку:

> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить, sql начал изучать только сейчас.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
create table employess 
(
  num number(4,0) primary key, 
  fname varchar(100) not null, 
  bday date, 
  gender char(1) default 'm' check(gender in ('f','m')),
  jobb varchar(30) not null,
  wagerate number(2,1) default 1 check(wagerate between 0.1 and 1.5), 
  sdate date not null, 
  address varchar(200) not null
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Видимо, так:

```
gender char(1) check(gender in('f','m')) default 'm',
```

Comment: Видимо не так - ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis - вы хоть проверяйте перед тем, как ответ дать.